# The half-prefixes

Tags: prefixes

Why is it *semicircle*, *hemisphere* and *demigod* and not some other combination of prefix and root?

I understand that the prefixes are relatively [productive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Productivity_(linguistics)), meaning that where you can use one, you can *sometimes* use the others. For example, *[semicircle](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/semicircle)*, *[hemicircle](http://thefreedictionary.com/hemicircle)*, and *[demicircle](http://merriam-webster.com/dictionary/demicircle)* are all acceptable, but the first is much more common than the other two.

My question is why *semicircle* became popular over the other variants? What factors affected the conventionalization of this form of the word? Did a famous author or publication popularize it? Do the languages of origin of the prefix and the root make a difference?

I have similar questions about *hemisphere* and *demigod*.

A related question is asked [here](https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20131030084647AA5O0ZI), but the answers are relatively vague.

Comment: The prefixes are productive, meaning you can apply them to root words pretty much as you see fit. "Semicircle" is *more conventional* than "hemicircle" and "demicricle", but the latter do work (http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hemicircle and http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/demicircle).

Comment: @Silenus Are there historical factors at play for the three words I mentioned then?

Comment: Sometimes they're interchangeable, as in ***hemitone = semitone***. But I don't know whether ***hemidemisemiquaver*** always occurs in that specific sequence. And until I just found [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Note_value) I had no idea there was such a thing as a ***demisemihemidemisemiquaver*** (which is apparently "rare"! :)

Comment: Most certainly, in the sense that certain words become popular for various socio-historical reasons. For example, *if* a famous author (e.g. Shakespeare) or publication (e.g. the Bible) used "semicircle" over "demicircle", the former might conventionalize over the latter (I'm not saying this happened, just pointing out that this is the kind of story you would tell). The etymology of the root words is another factor (some people like to keep etymological bloodlines pure). Maybe others can do the archaeology on the three words you mentioned.

Comment: @Silenus Thanks! Yes, that would be a fun story to bring up on a first date!

Comment: @Silenus I don't accept either that 'you can apply _hemi_ etc to root words pretty much as you want', or that these prefixes can be labelled 'productive' without qualification. A hemi-detached house? demidesert? heminomadic? demiglosses? hemisolid? demisweet? I'll let you find many other counterexamples.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, fair enough! I spoke carelessly. I meant that wherever you can use one, you can get away with using the others.

Comment: @Silenus See what sort of looks people give you if you tell them you live in a demi-detached. _They're not interchangeable_ in perhaps most cases.

Comment: Good point. Same goes for "I live in the northern semisphere."

Comment: @Silenus And _Indecent Proposal_ definitely doesn’t star Semi Moore. ;-)

Comment: @Edwin: The fact that we can rattle off so many usages where we *don't* find it acceptable to switch prefixes does rather suggest there might be some actual *principles* involved, as well as the vagaries of chance eventually leading to strong "idiomatically established preference" that we all easily remember.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Exactly. This is what I think I had in mind when I asked the question.

Comment: Here's a [potentially useful summary](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-the-prefixes-semi-hemi-and-demi) of the main issues.

Comment: @FumbleFingers If we follow the apparent pattern, a 1/512 note would presumably be a _hemidemisemihemidemisemiquaver_, at which point I’d say we’re well into the territory of ridiculous nonsense. And good luck saying it ten times fast.

Comment: My general expectation about differences like this is that they are almost always due to accidents of history and style. @FumbleFinger's link points out that they derive from different languages (Latin, Greek, French), so it likely depends on which language was popular to adopt from at the time a particular use became well known.

Answer (score 1):

The question is why 'semicircle' is more popular than other variants, and, more broadly, why do any words with those prefixes have a different preferred form, even though they mean the same.
Since no one has apparently followed up on [FumbleFingers' link](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-the-prefixes-semi-hemi-and-demi) or gave an answer, I'll summarize the answer here.

The last proposed factor seems to be the most relevant: the origin of the prefix and the rest of the word.

---

***Demi**-* is the youngest of the three. It comes from old French/Norman and found its way into English along with many other Norman words. *Demi* was initially written separately, and was seen as an adjective or a noun, not a prefix. It was generally combined with words that have a similar root in French, or words in fields dominated by the French language, such as heraldry, clothing, or arms. However, the Oxford English Dictionary states that, as a prefix it is:

> "Used with the senses ‘half, half-sized, partial(ly), curtailed, inferior’."

Looking at the OED, it seems other uses, such as 'demi-circle' stopped being used halfway through the 19th century.

An interesting definition, and, in a way, another difference with *semi* and *hemi*, is this:

> "With ordinary class-nouns, indicating a person or thing which has half the characteristics connoted by the name; or is half this and half not, half-and-half; hence sometimes with sense ‘of equivocal quality or character’"
>
> So 'demigod', but 'demi-beast', 'demi-Christian', and—my personal favourite— 'demi-Moor'.

On *demi-circle*, which appears to have been used a little in the 17th and 18th century, it says:

> **"A semicircle. Now rare"**

---

***Hemi***- comes from Greek, and is therefore the oldest of the three. It is most often prefixed to other words that stem from Greek. This is most visible in the fields of geometry and  chemistry.
The OED has this to add:

> "Several Greek words containing this element were in use as technical terms in later Latin, e.g. *hēmicyclium , hēmisphærium* [...] In the modern languages they are very numerous, not only in terms adopted or adapted < Greek (directly or through Latin), but in new formations, scientific or technical, < Greek, or on Greek analogies. Words formed < Latin have the corresponding prefix *semi*- prefix; but there are instances of hybridism in the use of both prefixes"

It also provides this definition, distinct from the other prefixes:

> "Half-; one half, the half, pertaining to or affecting one half; esp. in Anat., Biol., and Pathol. Pertaining to one of the two halves (right and left) of the body, or of any of its symmetrical organs."

On *hemicircle*, which was used for a bit in the early 17th century, the OED says:

> **"*Obs*. or *arch*.  A half circle, semicircle."**

---

***Semi***- comes from Latin. It is a rather direct translation of the Greek *hemi*- prefix, and is used in very similar cases (in Latin). Many Greek words containing *hemi*- were Latinized into *semi*. As Latin became the European language of science, *semi-* was often used in medicine and other sciences. The OED explains that the first use of the word was in compounds taken directly from Latin. It continues:

> "In the 16th–18th c., the number of permanent compounds was increased mainly by the accession of **terms more or less technical** (many of them adapted or imitated from Latin), such as *semibreve*, *semicircle*, or *semivowel*.   At the same time there was gradual enlargement of the scope of the prefix in the formation of general nonce-compounds, which became very frequent in the 19th c."

It also appears that 'semigod' in fact predates the use of 'demigod' by half a century, and that it was more popular in the 15th-17th century. Both are used to render the Latin 'semideus'.

---

---

**To sum it up:** there are actually many compounds of which multiple forms have existed simultaneously or consecutively. But most compounds today have one dominant prefix, largely influenced by usage in science and engineering. Whenever there *are* multiple forms still in use, they usually have very distinct meanings.
So while a 'semicolon' is a punctuation mark, used perhaps too little, a 'hemicolon' is the left or right half of the colon (i.e. the end part of the large intestine), and is probably used sufficiently ;)

Comment: Yeah, typically when there are multiple prefixes of this sort there is one Greek and one Latin (and, in this case, one French) and an attempt is made by academics to use the prefix that corresponds to the language of the root.  Of course, academics don't always get their way, so there are exceptions.